# MySQL connection pooling in Python2.7 doesn't work as expected. Facing issue with close() function of connection pool

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, mysql-connector-python

I have taken the python sample code for MySQL Connection pool and tried to execute it with django framework. I'm able to execute the queries and retrieve the data if I don't close the cursor and connection object. When I call close() function connection object it's failing with following error, Please help me to solve this.

> > ProgrammingError at /settings 
> >     1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
> >
> > Method: GET
> >
> > Request URL:    http://sample.app.com/settings
> >
> > Django Version: 1.11.5
> >
> > Exception Type: ProgrammingError
> >
> > Exception Value:    1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
> >
> > Exception Location: venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py in _auth_switch_request, line 256 Python Executable:   venv/bin/python2
> >
> > Python Version: 2.7.17

The code which I'm using, Coding in bold are creating the issue. If don't close connection, its working fine. when i close it doesn't work and throws an error.

**db_pool.py**

```
import mysql.connector.pooling

dbconfig = {
    "host":"127.0.0.1",
    "port":"3306",
    "user":"root",
    "password":"root",
    "database":"test",
}


class MySQLPool(object):
    """
    create a pool when connect mysql.
    """
    def __init__(self, host="127.0.0.1", port="3306", user="root",
                 password="root", database="test", pool_name="mypool",
                 pool_size=3):
        res = {}
        self._host = host
        self._port = port
        self._user = user
        self._password = password
        self._database = database

        res["host"] = self._host
        res["port"] = self._port
        res["user"] = self._user
        res["password"] = self._password
        res["database"] = self._database
        self.dbconfig = res
        self.pool = self.create_pool(pool_name=pool_name, pool_size=pool_size)

    def create_pool(self, pool_name="mypool", pool_size=3):
        """
        Create a connection pool
        """
        pool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(
            pool_name=pool_name,
            pool_size=pool_size,
            pool_reset_session=True,
            **self.dbconfig)
        return pool

    > > def close(self, conn, cursor):
    > > """ Here I'm facing issue, close is causing the issue. this close must release the connection object and add it to the connection pool. """
    > >   cursor.close()
    > >   conn.close()

    def execute(self, sql, args=None, commit=False):
        """
        Execute a sql
        """
        # get connection form connection pool.
        conn = self.pool.get_connection()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        if args:
            cursor.execute(sql, args)
        else:
            cursor.execute(sql)
        if commit is True:
            conn.commit()
            self.close(conn, cursor)
            return None
        else:
            res = cursor.fetchall()

            self.close(conn, cursor)
            return res
```

Using above code in another file **db_operation.py**

```
from db_pool import MySQLPool

def testing(request, bid, *args, **kwargs):

    mysql_pool = MySQLPool()
    query = "select * from test.table1;"
    result = mysql_pool.execute(query)
    print 'RESULT : ', result
```

Please help me to solve this or share if any best examples to use connection pool properly.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue. By default pool_reset_session is set to True and modified this to False. Now, it's working fine.

When pool_reset_session is true, it's resetting the session with default config's for host, user and no password. As per my current DB connection, it will not allow without password. So, pool_reset_session is caused an issue and solved it.

Thanks.